# How to include entire certification path when signing code with signtool?

Tags: code-signing

How can i include the entire certification path when signing code using [`signtool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Older versions of signtool would include the entire certification path in a digital signature. As it is now if i sign an executable with `signtool`:

```
signtool.exe" sign /v /f avatar.pfx -t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" app.exe
```

the signature is not valid:

[image]

This is because there is no certification path:

[image]

Binaries signed with the older version of signtool worked fine:

[image]

How do i tell signcode to include the entire certification path when signing?

What is the proper way to sign a binary?

---

**Update**: SignTool version `6.1.7600.16385`:

[image]

### See also

- [How can I sign an ActiveX control with a code signing certificate and be a verified publisher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814233/how-can-i-sign-an-activex-control-with-a-code-signing-certificate-and-be-a-verifi)
- [Signing WinForms ClickOnce app with Certificate Chain](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/signing-winforms-clickonce-app-certificate-chain-t3522706.html)
- [ClickOnce: Certificate cannot be validated](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/browse_thread/thread/8c46df2acf25d54/4c1c4221f69fa09e?pli=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `/ac` and pass the filename of the `.cer` in which your certificate is rooted (for Verisign it was called MSCV-VSClass3.cer last time I checked when signing kernel code or other special code).

```
signtool.exe sign /v /f "Avatar.pfx" 
      /ac "Thawte Code Signing CA - G2.cer" 
      -t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" app.exe
```

This should be given by your CA. Usually MS offers bundles for the various CAs it accepts within Windows.

See:

- [Windows root certificate program members](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125/en-us)
- [Cross-Certificates for Kernel Mode Code Signing](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/crosscert.mspx)

Either way, to my knowledge this is only required for kernel code and very specific other things (e.g. Windows Security Center).

Comment: Is this a workaround to the issue with signtool? Searching finds nobody doing this.

Comment: @Ian: I know it may sound ridiculous, but there was some change that was introduced with the signtool that came first with Vista or Vista SP1. Ever since, we're storing our certs inside the certificate store and it works perfectly fine. Of course /ac is only needed for special purposes. Also make sure your root certificates on the signing machine are up-to-date.

Comment: i found another guy here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814233/how-can-i-sign-an-activex-control-with-a-code-signing-certificate-and-be-a-verifi). He indicates that he managed to create a PFX that includes the root certificate, the intermediate signing certificate, the signing certificate and the private key. i've left a comment asking what command he used to place additional certificates in his `pfx` file. Our certificate provider, Thawte, provided us no other files (cer, pfx, or otherwise) for their root certificate, or intermediate certificates.

Comment: i always thought that all certificates must, ultimately, be signed by a trusted root certificate. Windows ships with a few handfuls of trusted root certificates - so no network access *is* needed; it's already here on the local machine.

Comment: @Ian: odd. Good luck with that other guy then. And yes, on the local machine perhaps, but drivers at the earliest stages of bootup don't have access to the certificate store. And I suppose it might have to do with root certificates getting replaced every few years as well ...

Answer (score 2):

If you use Thawte then download their [`primaryca.cer`](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR1406).

Download to file `primaryca.cer` and sign your file with:

```
signtool sign /f certificate.pfx /p PASSWORD /ac primaryca.cer APP.exe.
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for authenticode signing

- Windows Authenticode Portable Executable Signature Format ([`.docx`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/authenticode_pe.docx) )

says that the PKCS #7 SignedData structure...

> ...contains the signer certificate and any intermediate certificates, but typically does not contain the root certificate.

However, as I discovered in a bit of a 'DOH!' moment, signtool.exe must be able to find the certificates to include them.

The leaf certificate is provided on the command line.  But the identification of the remaining certificates up the chain does not include where to find the certificates.  signtool does check the system certificate store, so if they are found there, they are added to the binary.  If they are not found, signtool only puts the leaf certificate into the signed binary.

Note that if the intermediate certificates are not in the signed binary, but are in the system certificate store of the system checking the signature, the binary will still pass verification, because the chain can be resolved.

Also note that the exclusion of the root from the signed binary makes sense, given that the root must independently be on the system checking the signature for it to be trusted, so it would be ignored anyway.  (The only real benefit to including the root in the binary would be if someone wanted to import the root cert manually, which is almost always a very bad idea.)