# How can I introduce a cross signing certificate into a chain?

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I maintain a java applet that is locally deployed.  I recently purchased a code signing certificate from Go Daddy (it was inexpensive, and they already host our site).  My certificate chain is as follows (all files are available at https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki):

1. my company
2. `gdig2.cer`
3. `gdroot-g2.crt`

Unfortunately, this root is not installed by default on Windows 7 (used by IE) or the Windows JRE (used by other browsers, I think).  Manually installing the root certificate is doable, but it requires my users to have administrator access or run unfamiliar commands (it also doesn't make much sense from a security standpoint to say "you can trust my applet, and to prove it, run this command on your computer").

I would like to change my certificate chain to

1. my company
2. `gdig2.cer`
3. `gdroot-g2_cross.crt`
4. `gd-class2-root.crt`

which seems to be more prevalent (for example, it is the one in the Windows JRE, and is used to validate https://www.godaddy.com, which gets it into Windows 7).  Go Daddy is not able to do this for me ("our support for using one of our Code Signing Certificates is limited"), so I'm left doing this on my own.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654543/how-to-create-pfx-with-my-chain-of-certificates/6655022#6655022), my most promising approach has been the following (on Mac OS X 10.6):

1. Convert my certificate into pem format:
   `$ openssl pkcs12 -in myCert.p12 -out myCert.pem -nodes`
2. Use a text editor to open myCert.pem, delete `gdroot-g2.crt`, and paste in  `gdroot-g2_cross.crt` and `gd-class2-root.crt` (openssl appears not to care about the order of the certificates, but I put them in the order shown above)
3. Convert the certificates back to p12 format:
   `$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCert.pem -out combined.p12`

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work.  Calling
`$ keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore combined.p12 -v`
shows that my certificate chain extends through `gdig2.cer`, and stops.  The problem appears to be that `gdroot-g2_cross.cer` doesn't certify `gdig2.cer`:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile gd-class2-root.cer gdroot-g2_cross.cer
gdroot-g2_cross.cer: OK
$ cat gd-class2-root gdroot-g2_cross.cer > gdRootCross.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile gdRootCross.pem gdig2.cer
gdig2.cer: /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2  
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

But everything looks ok to me:

```
$ openssl x509 -in gdig2.cer -text -noout
. . .
Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
keyid:3A:9A:85:07:10:67:28:B6:EF:F6:BD:05:41:6E:20:C1:94:DA:0F:DE
. . .
$ openssl x509 -in gdroot-g2_cross.cer -text -noout
. . .
Subject: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., OU=https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
3A:9A:85:07:10:67:28:B6:EF:F6:BD:05:41:6E:20:C1:94:DA:0F:DE
. . .
```

This leads me to think that I'm not using the cross certificate correctly, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  (I've also tried appending the two new certificates to my original chain, to which `openssl verify` says `error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate`.)  I'm almost willing to believe that it's not possible to change the root certificate, but that seems to be the entire point of cross certificates.  **How can I introduce a cross certificate into my certificate chain in order to be verified by a different root certificate authority?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You just have one certificate signed by the first authority; and one certificate signed by the second authority - both are having the same public key / fingerprint and subject line. That's it.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case.  I guess it's on to plan B: telling my users how to install a new root certificate.