# azure website ssl with SAN identifies as *.azurewebsites.net

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, azure-web-app-service, sni

I am trying to move a website into Azure (Azure Website). I have everything moved, except the ssl isn't working. The error that comes up says

`You attempted to reach [subdomain].[domain].com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.azurewebsites.net ...`

I think it may have something to do with my certificate. The cert is a UCC cert (multiple SAN) through GoDaddy. I did not rekey the cert when I moved the site from the old server to the Azure Website. The old server was managed using Parallels. Here is what I did to move the cert:

I logged into Parallels on the old server. I opened the SSL screen, where I could see the 4 parts of the cert (csr, private key, certificate, CA certificate). I copied the text for each of those (including the `---Begin Certificate---` and `---End Certificate---` lines.  EDIT: the private key began with `---Begin RSA Private Key---` and ended with `---End RSA Private key`), and I pasted the data to create 4 .txt files. I then renamed the txt files so that I had 4 files named `CAcertificate.cer`, `certificate.cer`, `privateKey.pem`, and `cert.cer`. They were all saved in the c:\ directory (root).

I then pulled up OpenSSL and ran the following command:

`pkcs12 -export -in c:\certificate.cer -inkey c:\privateKey.pem -out c:\certificate.pfx -certfile c:\CAcertificate.cer`

I entered a password twice, and out popped a certificate.pfx file.

I uploaded that file to my Azure Website. The UCC Cert applies to 4 subdomains. I have my Azure Website set up with only one of those subdomains as a domain name. After uploading the file, I went to `SSL Binding`, and chose that subdomain, matched it with the cert I just uploaded, and chose "SNI SSL." I saved it, and all looked good.

Unfortunately, when I browse to the subdomain, I get the error I listed at the beginning.

I have a CName set up to forward from that subdomain to the Azure Website. I also have an A record set up to point from that subdomain to the IP Address of the Azure Website. The site is pulling up as I would expect, except for the ssl certificate error.

Did I generate the .pfx file incorrectly? Is there something I need to change in Azure or my domain registrar? I noticed that I could download a .pem file from the parallels panel. It contained all 4 parts of the cert in one file. I didn't know what I could do with that.

Comment: Are you sure the private key is correctly included? Are there any intermediate/root CAs missing from your certificate path? Would you mind adding "with SAN" or something similar to your question title?

Comment: Regarding the private key, I followed the process above twice. I included it by making at .txt file and pasting in the "Private Key" from the old server. Regarding intermediate/root CAs, the certificate worked fine on the old server. I don't understand what could have changed in that area to make it not work...

Comment: If there is a unknown root or intermediate CA in the certificate path then azure website's IIS/SSL endpoint handling will probably notice this (correctly) as an issue and not use it. You could use *certmgr.msc* under Windows to install and review your certificate and its path. It also allows to then export a .pfx containing all certificates in the path.

Comment: I installed the cert to my local machine. I opened certmgr.msc, and found the cert. When I look at "Certification Path" I see the following: `Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority` -> `Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority` -> `www.[domain].com`. In the details, under `Subject Alternative Name` I see each of the subdomains entered as `DNS = [subdomain].[domain].com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A missing root or intermediate certification authority can cause this behavior as documented in [this article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/09/the-complete-guide-to-loading-free-ssl.html) (written by a Microsoft MVP).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6655022/468244) shows how to export the full certificate chain including the private key using OpenSSL for Windows.

If the certificate is already installed in your local Windows machine you can follow [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737187(v=ws.10)) and be sure to select

- **Yes, export the private key** and
- **Include all certificates in the certification path if possible**.

This will create a .pfx file containing your certificate, its private key as well as all intermediate and root CAs.